# Python3.7 installing http with pip3 not working

Tags: linux, http, pip

when running `pip3 install http` I get the following error:

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
 command: /usr/bin/python3.7 -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-w8rp368e/http/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-w8rp368e/http/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-t6p61b0y
     cwd: /tmp/pip-install-w8rp368e/http/
Complete output (7 lines):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/tmp/pip-install-w8rp368e/http/setup.py", line 3, in <module>
    import http
  File "/tmp/pip-install-w8rp368e/http/http/__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
    from request import Request
ImportError: cannot import name 'Request' from 'request' (/home/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/request/__init__.py)
----------------------------------------
```

ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.

have the latest version of pip, requests and have tried all the found answers, but the error is still being thrown. Help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

`http`, as in [this package](https://pypi.org/project/http/), was last updated in 2012 and was written for python 2. It therefore does not work in newer python versions.

But you can just use the `http` built-in module. See [here](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/http.html). "built-in" means that it should be available in your python version already.

Try:

```
import http
```